# angularJs email validation failure

Tags: angularjs, validation

The angular email validation is not working for me, that I'm not allowed to type any text in the email text box.

Following is my HTML:

```html
<form name="locationSettingsForm" ng-submit="vm.saveLocationSettings()" class="form">
  <input class="userInput" style="width:40%" type="email" name="email"
   maxlength="50" data-ng-model="vm.location.email" required
   ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/" />
   <label class="validationErrorText" data-ng-show="locationSettingsForm.email.$dirty && locationSettingsForm.email.$error.email">Email is invalid</label>
   <label class="validationErrorText" data-ng-show="locationSettingsForm.email.$dirty && locationSettingsForm.email.$error.required">Email is required</label>
</form>
```

Initially I tried without the ng-patter. I only used type='email', but in both instances it didnt work. I can't type any text.

[image]

Comment: which version of angular are you using ?

Comment: v1.3.2. I'm checking on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern

```
ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$/"
```

it should work

Comment: I know, I followed this from Angular site. But when I add type=email, it doesnt allow typing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try below code....

```
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" ng-model="email" name="uEmail" placeholder="Email Id" required>
        <div ng-show="form.uEmail.$dirty && form.uEmail.$invalid">Invalid:
  <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
  <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
```